# Use AJAX returned IMAGE URL from Django MEDIA folder

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to use the returned image URL (via AJAX call) as a div's background. That URL is referenced to Django's MEDIA folder.

Folder Structure

```
website

    media
        music
            image.jpg

    music
        templates
            player.html
```

Every field from the object works, altho I can't seem to make use of the returned image URL.

views.py

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def change_song(request):
    featured_song_id = request.session['featured_song']
    song_list = Song.objects.all().order_by('-date') # list of objects
    if request.method == "POST":
        request.session['featured_song'] = request.POST['song_id']
        featured_song_id = request.session['featured_song']
    obj = Song.objects.get(pk=featured_song_id)
    serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [obj])
    serialized_song_list = serializers.serialize('json', song_list)
    string_render = render_to_string('music/player.html')
    context = {
        'html': string_render,
        'obj': serialized_obj,
        'song_list': serialized_song_list,
    }
    return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)
```

AJAX/jQuery/Javascript

```
    $('a.play').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var song_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var this_url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this_url,
            data: {
                'song_id': song_id,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data.obj);
                image = obj[0]['fields']['image'];
                $('.player-image').css('background', 'url(/media/' + image + ') no-repeat center; background-size: 100% 100%;');
            }
        });
    });
```

I also tried inside the `url()`:

```
image
"image"
/media/ + image
"'/media/" + image"'"
```

EDIT: Following Ivan Starostin's comment:

image value is `music/images/0_default.jpg`, taken from `console.log(image);`

concatenated value of '/media/'+ image is `/media/music/images/0_default.jpg`

When going to url, it displays the image correctly:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/music/images/0_default.jpg
```

I'm trying to override a working image from django's `{{ object.image.url }}`that seems to be the same format: [element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvPSU.jpg)

Note: the image 0_default.jpg exists and it is placed on the same folder as the URL from the inspected element

Comment: Please check and update your question with this info: what is the `image` value, what is the final concatenated url value, what is the http status code when you try to open this url manually.

Comment: So the Django part seems to be working fine same as JS part: you can see final HTML with expected image URL in element's style attribute. Perhaps you are doing this in different environments. Could be you've put the image that is working fine days before and have executed `collectstatic` or moved it **somewhere else out of project folder**. However you're saying that via direct link you can view this image. Please check HTTP responses in browser dev tools and any errors in the console. And try CTRL+SHIFT+R to reload all content.

Comment: Did all that. All the images are in the same folders like they always were.

Comment: So, no error statuses in "Network" tab, no error messages in "Console", no errors in Django log, correct image URL, expected HTML and CSS, right? Perhaps your CSS or HTML is rendered not as you expect and (logical) error is somewhere there.